# Cannot connect to SQL Server remotely: Network Interface Error 26

Tags: sql-server, connection, firewall

Today I tried to enable remote connections to a SQL Server that is physically located on a different country. I do have access to it through Remote Desktop, however I can't connect through my local SQL Server Management Studio client. I get a network error that states the server was not found or is not accessible (Network Interface Error 26).

I already tried the following:

- Enabled the "Allow remote connections to this server" in SQL Server Management Studio
- Made sure the SQL Server service was running
- Made sure the correct server name was typed.
- Enabled TCP/IP Protocols and Named Pipes in SQL Server Configuration Management (and established the port 1433 on TCP/IP Properties, because it was set to 56733)
- Created a rule for the Windows Firewall to allow communication through port 1433 & service `sqlserver.exe` (both TCP and UDP, allowing connections from everywhere)
- Restarted the service through SQL Server and Control Panel > Services screen

The server name has the structure `ServerName\InstanceName` and I can login with both SQL Server and Windows authentication.

Could someone please give me a hand with this?

Comment: Look in the SQL Error log to ensure it's listening on the IPs and Ports you expect, and test from a remote client with powershell: `PS C:\> test-netconnection -Port 1433 -ComputerName ServerName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a named instance i.e. SERVER\INSTANCE, it's highly unlikely that it would have been on 1433. It would have been a dynamic port and using the SQL browser service.

Was it still set to a dynamic port (i.e. the default)? If so, was 1434 allowed as well?

Was anything else on 1433? (i.e. a default instance)?

Have you tried connecting to the IP address, and port directly? i.e x.x.x.x,port

Comment: Trying the IP address + port directly worked! I only had to disable all but one of the IPs in the TCP/IP Properties tab (only left enabled the one with the IP I used to connect to). However I'm still unable to login with server/instance combination.

Comment: SERVER\INSTANCE will require 2 things. You'll need SERVER to resolve correctly with DNS. Then the client sends a UDP request to port 1434. (That has to be open too) If the browser service is running, then it tells the client which port the server instance is on.

Comment: What I prefer (by a long way) is to use a specific name in your application configuration (i.e. something like HRServer instead of SERVER\INSTANCE) and then use a SQL Client Alias to map that to where the server is. Then your app knows nothing about it. However, an alias is just a registry entry on each client. If we do that, we push the alias out using group policy.

Comment: And if your instance is on 1433, you don't need the SERVER\INSTANCE at all, you could just use SERVER as 1433 is the default port.